# Regarding the Chrome and FF multi thread (Process) how to do load test with web protocol?

Tags: performance, testing, load, performance-testing

I wonder if some one solved the issue of browser multi thread with a request response script for load test

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use real Chrome and FF browsers for load test you can consider the following options:

1. [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)

   > Selenium-Grid allows you run your tests on different machines against different browsers in parallel. That is, running multiple tests at the same time against different machines running different browsers and operating systems. Essentially, Selenium-Grid support distributed test execution. It allows for running your tests in a distributed test execution environment.
2. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) with the [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) plugin. This way you will be able to control concurrency and get performance metrics in form of [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simulating web browser concurrency is something most load testing tools do very badly, if at all. We have tried to do this in [k6](https://k6.io) by letting each VU (virtual user) use multiple, concurrent TCP connections to fetch things in parallel. There is a special API function - [http.batch()](https://docs.k6.io/docs/batch-requests) - that enables this functionality. http.batch() accepts multiple URLs as input parameters, and will fetch as many as possible in parallel.

Like Dmitri writes, Jmeter has a plugin that provides concurrency - sort of. However, what it actually does (unless I'm misinformed) is to spread out requests over multple VUs. Each VU will still only use one concurrent connection, which means that if you e.g. want to simulate 100 real browser users, you may need to fire up 1,000 VUs to do so realistically. This is not very different from what you would get with any other load testing tool, in my opinion: all of them allow you to start more VUs to create more concurrency and more traffic.

I'd say that apart from k6 and maybe one or perhaps two other tools (and Jmeter is not one of them), your only option if you want to really simulate the way browsers behave, is to use Selenium Grid or something similar to fire up a large number of real, actual browsers to do the load testing. The drawback is that real browsers are very expensive to run: they want lots of CPU and memory. But they provide the by far best browser "simulation".